# how to add or remove windowMenu option of actionMenuBar

Tags: delphi

I want to know, how to add or remove windowMenu option of actionMenuBar component, i have a mdi aplication i can add the option but later I can't remove it

sorry my english

i have this:

```
   //add windowmenu and works fine       
   procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
    Form1.ActionMainMenuBar1.WindowMenu := '&Ventana';
   end;

   //remove windowmenu but dont work
   procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
    Form1.ActionMainMenuBar1.WindowMenu := '';
   end;
```

Comment: Did you try simply to remove the corresponding menu option from the menu?

Answer (score 3):

```
type
  ActionMainMenuBarAccess = class(TActionMainMenuBar);

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ActionMainMenuBar1.WindowMenu := '';
  ActionMainMenuBarAccess(ActionMainMenuBar1).FWindowMenuItem := nil;
  ActionMainMenuBarAccess(ActionMainMenuBar1).RefreshMDIMenu;
end;
```

See also this [QualityCentral report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=20278).

Comment: +1. I think this is the first time I discovered a VCL component containing a protected *field*. Interesting...

Comment: @AndriyM It's not extraordinarily: `TWinControl.FDoubleBuffered`, `TWinControl.FDesignSize`, `TComponent.FComponentStyle`, `TCustomForm.FFormState`, `TCustomListBox.FMoving`, etc...

Comment: Indeed, those are protected fields too, thanks. I'm amazed that I was unable to come across them before.